# The way to differ two functions with the same name in available scope in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a pretty straightforward example, but in the same time it is confused. It is shown below:

```
abstract class AbstractClass[A] {

  def function1(elem: A)(f: A => A): AbstractClass[A]
  
  object AbstarctClass {
    def function2(f: A => A) = new AbstractClass[A] {
      override def function1(elem: A)(f: A => A): AbstractClass[A]  = 
        // some code
    }
  }
}
```

Is there way to differ two functions, that receives function1 and function2, in scope of function1? I know, we can call them in different way and they will be used properly, but I'm interested how can we differentiate them in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Update parent class declaration:

```scala
abstract class AbstractClass[A] { parent =>
  // ...
}
```

Then

```scala
parent.function1(..)
```